# How to copy cell value only if other two cells matches

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I have an excel file containing two spreadsheet as shown below. I want to update value Comm Level in Sheet 1 with Comm Level in sheet 2 provided that Modem ID in sheet 1 matches Modem ID in sheet 2. How to do automatically do this in Libre office ? Can someone suggest me some formula or script which will work in Libre office as I do not have license for MS office.

```
Sheet 1

Modem ID |  Comm Level 
-----------------------
70000    |    90
70001    |    90
70004    |    90
70007    |    90
70010    |    90

Sheet 2

Modem ID |  Comm Level 
-----------------------
70001    |    80
70002    |    90
70003    |    60
70004    |    90
70009    |    90
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have no clue how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Modem ID` is in A1 on both sheets. In C2 of Sheet1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2.A:B,2,0),B2)
```

Looks for a corresponding value with [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) where a match exists and if not found defaults to existing value with [IFERROR](https://help.libreoffice.org/5.0/Calc/Information_Functions#bm_id31452061).